# Login 415 error while logging in the application using axios

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, service, axios

I am trying to get user to login to the website by using axios but it keeps on giving me 415 error while posting please if any one could help tell me.I have done the previous post request on signup and it had worked perfectly but i didint seem to understand what is wrong now.

Reducer

```
import LoginService from "../API/LoginService";
    import store from '../store/store';
    const initialState  =   {
        LOGIN:{},
        loading:false,
        success:{},
        error:{},
    };

    const LOGIN_REDUCER=(state= initialState,action)=>{
        const payload = action.payload;

        switch(action.type){
            case "LOGIN":
                LoginService.UserLogin(payload)
                .then(response=>{
                    store.dispatch({type:'LOGIN_SUCCESS',payload:response});

                })
                .then(error=>{
                    store.dispatch({type:'LOGIN_ERROR',payload:error});
                    });
                    console.log(action.payload)
                return {
                    ...state,
                    loading:true


                };
                break;
            case "LOGIN_SUCCESS":

                return{

                    ...state,
                    loading:false,
                    LOGIN:payload.data,



                };     

                break;
            case "LOGIN_ERROR":
                    return{
                        ...state,
                        loading:false,
                        error:payload.data,
                    };  
                    break;

                default:
                    return state;
                    break;
        }

    }

    export default LOGIN_REDUCER;
```

Action

```
 export  default class Login{
        static Create(payload){
            return {
                type: "LOGIN",
                payload:payload
            };
        }
    }
    console.log('Success')
```

LoginService

```
   import Axios from "axios";
    import API_URL from '../common';
    export default class LoginService{
        static UserLogin(payload){
            return Axios.post(API_URL+'/api/TokenAuth/Authenticate',payload)
            .then(handleResponse) 
            .then(response=>{
                return response;
            });
        }

    }
    console.log("create")
    function handleResponse(response){
        if(response.status ===200){
            return response.data;
        }
        else if(response.status ===401){
            const error = (response.data && response.data.message) || response.statusText;
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
    }
```

Handlesubmit in the component

```
 async  handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        this.setState({ submitted: true });
        const { userNameOrEmailAddress, password } = this.state;
        await store.dispatch(Login.Create(userNameOrEmailAddress, password));
    }
```

Comment: Your are calling api inside your reducer, this is against the rules of redux. Reducers must be pure functions. First learn the [redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers) basics, and apply to your app. With this code I don't think anybody can help.

Comment: I have got the problem i have to pass accesstoken in the headers of api can you please tell me how it can be done usinng axios @SuleymanSah